# Two lines of text in a single grid row

Tags: python, text, grid, tkinter, row

Does anybody know if it's possible to put two lines of text in a single row using `grid` in TKinter?

If I make the font small enough, can I distribute the text in two lines?

Comment: Can you be more precise in your question? What are the two "lines of text" (two or one labels? another widget?). Is the initial wrapping intentionnal? What is your expected output (if you put two lines on one row, it's difficult to keep talking of lines...). You may also consider posting a minimal example exhibiting your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import Tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> tk.Label(master=root, text="Line1\nLine2").grid(row=0)
>>> root.mainloop()
```

Worked for me and produced an image like this:

[image: root window]

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for. Do you think it's possible to make, say, only the first line bold or with a different fontsize?

Comment: @maupertius: you cannot use multiple fonts in a single label, but you can use multiple labels or you can use a text widget which lets you change fonts and colors all you want.

Comment: @BryanOakley: do you know how to add multiple labels to the same row of a grid (without creating frames)?

Comment: @maupertius "without creating frames" -- Why not use a frame?  That's their entire purpose.  You can achieve a similar effect using the rowspan option to the grid method, but ultimately, that will be confusing and probably a lot more work...

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple items in one cell but it is highly unusual, may have surprising behavior, and there are better ways to accomplish the same effect.

For example, the grid is invisible so you can have as many rows as you want to achieve any look you can imagine. Also, the definition of "item" is pretty loose -- you can create a frame, and in that frame put two labels, and that frame can go in a single row using grid to give the appearance of two lines of text in a single grid row. You can also use a text widget which lets you put as many lines of text that you want.

Comment: I used `anchor="n"` for the top row and `anchor="s"` for the bottom one. Thanks for your help!